# Convert Joomla textarea into Editor in Backend Custom Component in Administrator Section

Tags: joomla, editor, joomla2.5

Can you help in, i have a custom component in which the text area is displayed in joomla backend
Code is

```
 <td height="25" valign="top"><?php echo JText::_( 'Long Description' ); ?>:</td>
 <td valign="top">
 <div id="clsTableTdPadd">  
 <textarea name="n_description" id="n_description" style="width:80%; height:400px" class="inputbox" >
 <?php echo stripcslashes($row->n_description);?></textarea></div></td>
 </div></td>
```

How to display Joomla default Editor (which is Tinymce by default) instead of text area in it

This is for Joomla 2.5 . 
Any help or suggestions pls

**Further Edit**
Have made following changes basis comments

```
     <?php
     $editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
     $params = array( 'smilies'=> '0' ,
             'style'  => '1' ,  
             'layer'  => '0' , 
             'table'  => '0' ,
             'clear_entities'=>'0'
             );
     echo $editor->display( 'n_description', stripslashes($row->n_description), '400', '400', '20', '20', false, null, null, null, $params );
            ?>
```

The editor is displaying, saving too. But when making edit - its not displaying in above

**Edited**
Hello, the editor is only showing toggle editor button below underneath
But when i went to see my articles in article manager - it showing all buttons like image, pagebreak, articles etc

How to show these tabs in my custom component too. Where i have put editor

[image: Editor Buttn]

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getEditor

Comment: Thanks Lodder, have made some changes with Joomla editor link as given. However - to my bad - i am still not able to get it done. Have appended the code in edit. Could you suggest a solution pls

Comment: Thanks Lodder for guiding too !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass id, name ,class explicitly.

Just give some name as first argument it will set the id and name .

```
$editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
$params = array( 'smilies'=> '0' ,
                 'style'  => '1' ,  
                 'layer'  => '0' , 
                 'table'  => '0' ,
                 'clear_entities'=>'0'
                 );
echo $editor->display( 'n_description', '$your_string', '400', '400', '20', '20', false, null, null, null, $params );
```

Comment: Thanks Jobin, Editor is well displaying. only issue now is content when published - i cant edit it after saving once. Have put in the code, as 2nd revised edit - how to get it corrected

Comment: just set second argument as your value when the editor is in edit stage check my edits

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is great, but as i been novice in this and still learning, the editor is showing :- 'echo stripslashes($row->n_description); as a command rather than the content. Could you advise for a solution to it.

Comment: Thanks for your time Jobin. Solution works perfect. Appreciate your help !!

Comment: Jobin - a more thing - i have appended an image, the editor is showing only toggle editor button underneath. I have choosen extended display - still the other like image, article, slider, etc are not shoiwng below editor. Is there separate setting for it !!

Comment: That options are related to Article only like adding module positions,images, etc also if you are using any extension like K2 it will also add some custom option with article section that is not part of your editor, By this method its load the default editor hope its make sense..